# Nutch agent rotate

Tags: ant, lucene, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to use rotate agent feature in nutch-1.10, down below is my configuration in nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>http.agent.rotate</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
        If true, instead of http.agent.name, alternating agent names are
        chosen from a list provided via http.agent.rotate.file.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>http.agent.rotate.file</name>
    <value>agents.txt</value>
    <description>
        File containing alternative user agent names to be used instead of
        http.agent.name on a rotating basis if http.agent.rotate is true.
        Each line of the file should contain exactly one agent
        specification including name, version, description, URL, etc.
    </description>
</property>
```

Also, here is the content of my agents.txt file

"NutchCVS/0.7 Nutch http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/bot.html nutch-agent@lucene.apache.org"

I've tried all kinds of ways to set agents.txt, when I tried to grep the 'agent' in hadoop.log, the agent remains to be the one I set in http.agent.name. I also ran 'ant runtime' to recompile the project after making changes. Please help me figure out what should be wrong. (I think it's the agents.txt file, but I don't know what is the right format of agents)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a local server and crawl on your localhost and check the server logs to see if the agent actually changes or not.

I had come across a similar issue, but when I checked the server logs, the agent was actually rotating.